# .net core 2.1 on redirect from another location the cookie value is always null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using custom authorization mechanism where I store the current user session in the cookie. Each time someone visits website the ActionFilter kicks in where it does stuff to validate the cookie value and the state of the session.

The problem I encountered is - I have to `POST` some data to a different website (https://differentUrl.com) where I am passing my websites returnUrl (https://mywebsiteUrl.com). The different website, after the job is done, sends back `POST` response to my returnURL. After this happens, the cookie, which I try to get, is always `null`.

Creating cookie like this (this happens on login):

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor; //Injected via DI
...
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions()
{
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10),
    Secure = true,
    HttpOnly = false,
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None //Still sets as Lax in browser
};

this._contextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("SomeKey", "myEncryptedCookieValue", cookieOptions);
```

Retrieving cookie after redirect:

```
var cookieDataString = this._contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["SomeKey"];
```

The `cookieDataString` is always `null`.

It works fine while I'm on the same site, but when I'm getting redirected back from another website, then it's always `null`

**Update 1:**

After some research I found out that this problem could cause `SameSite` policy. Found this article [Using same site cookie attribute](https://dzone.com/articles/using-the-same-site-cookie-attribute-to-prevent-cs) which says that `lax` is not the thing you want to use when you receive `POST` method to your website. Creating cookie I set cookie options as `SameSiteMode.None`. As it didn't work I found out that you have to set `MinimumSameSitePolicy` in startup middleware.

```
app.UseCookiePolicy(
    new CookiePolicyOptions()
    {
        MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
    });
```

After deleting the old cookie and creating new one, it stills creates it with `lax` policy.

Comment: Is the browser perhaps set to delete cookies as soon as a site is left? Have you used the browser's developer tools (press F12) to look at the cookies?

Comment: The cookie is still there after I reload the page. It doesn't dissapear. Cookie values in request are always array[0] on redirect from different url. The problem could be in `SameSite` policy I guess.

Comment: _sends back POST response to my returnURL. After this happens, the cookie, which I try to get, is always null_, read it, understand it. You post an return url and should **redirect** the user back, not calling the endpoint form the other application

Comment: @Tseng _post response_ as it redirects to my provided returnURL with post parameters. Only if you ment, that I load the page in the different location, then I don't.

Comment: Is the return url mapped to an get action? But shouldnt make any difference, its just that the browser calls get on the redirect. Do you maybe redirect to http when you came from https?  if cookie is set to https only browser wont send it on http requests

Comment: Yes, the scheme is passed correctly `https` and it's mapped correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and playing around with different test cases I found out that it was truly `SameSite` policy which was working as it should. The main problem was that it didn't allow me to set `SameSite = SameSiteMode.None`, even after I added `MinimumSitePolicy`.

After some time browsing documentation I found this [General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) .net core 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

All I had to do is add these lines in `ConfigureServices()`:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

And add `app.UseCookiePolicy();` in `Configure()`.

After these fixes I finally removed `Lax` from the cookie and after the redirect I finally got a value from my cookie.

Comment: You save my life :)